# SAML: Communication between Service Providers?

Tags: asp.net, saml

I've been tasked with writing a SP (Service Provider) for SAML v2.0 in ASP.NET, and I wonder the following;

If a user logs in on the main SP for a service (where my SP becomes accessible for a user as an anchor/link, unless previously bookmarked), and then requests access to my SP, how should I handle their login?

They will have logged in and become authorized by the IdP on the main SP, but how will that SP tell my SP that the user is logged in? 
Will I have to send a new authorization request to the IdP to determine whether the user is logged in or should it be passed on as post data/redirect with a query string from the SP?

I've read the [technical overview](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf) as well as the [basics](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/20520/SAMLV2.0-basics-Oct2006.pdf), but they don't cover this part.

*I will contact the main SP and ask how to proceed, but I  wanted to cover my bases first and see if there's a standard way on how to deal with this situation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to have the "main SP" construct the link so that IDP-Init SSO is initiated for users to log into your application. So the user would show up with a new Assertion from the IDP (customer) to your SP.

You could also have them directly link to your site to invoke SP-Init SSO for the given Identity Provider/Customer.

Either way you choose to do this will require you to handle multiple use cases and options for SAML 2.0. You can have this up and running in short order if you want to check out the SaaS Partner Program offered by Ping Identity. www.pingidentity.com

Let me know if you'd like more info on what we've seen other

Comment: I think we'll have to go with your second option. Thank you for the clarification, and the offer!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do SP-initiated SSO, you either need for there to be only one identity provider that you might need to send authentication requests to, or you need some means of determining the proper identity provider for a particular user -- either the user needs to provide some IdP-identifying info (such as StackOverflow does when you want to log in using your Google or other ID) or there may be something embedded in the URL.  (For the app I work on, different clients have their own site domains, so IdPs get mapped to those.)

So, yes, if you're going to go the SP-initiated route, you will need to make an authentication request to the IdP to determine who the user is, and you will want to use RelayState to get them back to the originally requested page.  If they're already authenticated at the IdP, then most likely this exchange will happen without requiring any input from the user.